# Split Array based on Test-Connection in a form

Tags: forms, powershell, arraylist, split

I am using PowerShell Studio to create a multiform script, and am running into a bit of trouble.

I'm trying to split the $HostList ArrayList into $OnlineHosts and $OfflineHosts based on Test-Connection.

I know this command is supposed to work, I just tested it on one of my normal ps1 scripts by immediately doing a Write-Host of the online and offline arrays. Here is the section of working code from my ps1:

```
Clear-Host  
$HostList = Get-Content "$Home\Documents\Scripts\ComputerList.txt"   
Write-Host "Pinging selected computers to verify connection..."

$OnlineHosts, $OfflineHosts = $HostList.Where({Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet},'Split')

$OnlineHosts
pause
$OfflineHosts
pause

Clear-Host
Write-Host "Could not contact the following computers:`n`n$OfflineHosts`n`nThe following computers are online:`n`n$OnlineHosts`n`nContinue anyways?" -ForegroundColor Red 
$ReadHost= Read-Host " (y/n) "  
Switch ($ReadHost)   
{ 
     Y  {Write-Host "Yes, Continuing to main menu."} 
     N  {Write-Host "No, preparing to exit" ; Pause ; Exit}   
Default {Write-Host "Yes, Continuing to main menu." }
}
```

However, in my Powershell Studio Project, it does not work. A little context: this is a new form that being passed the $HostList variable from a parent form. I tested that the child form is receiving the variable by doing Write-Host "$HostList woohoo!" I tested placing the Test-Connection code both into 
and outside of the $formTest_Load command. Honestly I'm not sure what exactly to put or not put into the $formTest_Load command, so information about that would be helpful as well.

Here's the code from my PowerShell Studio Project:

```
param ( [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
       [string]$global:HostList ) 

$global:OnlineHosts = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
Write-Host "$HostList woohoo!"    

$formTest_Load =   
{ 
     $OnlineHosts.Add($HostList) 
     $OnlineHosts, $OfflineHosts = $HostList.Where({Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet  },'Split')
}
```

Here is the error code I receive when I run my PowerShell Studio program:

> ERROR: Test-Connection : Generic failure formPing.psf (14, 49): 
>   ERROR: At Line: 14 char: 49 
>   ERROR: + ... neHosts =$HostList.Where({Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 Quiet }, 'Spl ...
>   ERROR:+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
>   ERROR: + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-Connection], ManagementException 
>   ERROR: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Test ConnectionCommand 
>   ERROR:

My Test-Connection code seems to be character by character the same as from my old ps1 file.

Can anyone see what might be causing the error?

Thanks.

Also, here is information about what I am running:
-Windows 10 Pro 
-PowerShell Studio 2018
     -version 5.5.152.0
     -64 bit

Run the following code in ISE and you will see what I am trying to do:

```
$HostList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$HostList += HostName 
$HostList += "FakeComputer"
Clear-Host

Write-Host "HostList contains: $HostList"
pause
Clear-Host

Write-Host "Verifying connection to target hosts..."
$OnlineHosts, $OfflineHosts = $HostList.Where({Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet }, 'Split')
Clear-Host

Write-Host "HostList contains: $HostList`n"
Write-Host "OnlineHosts contains: $OnlineHosts`n"
Write-Host "OfflineHosts contains: $OfflineHosts`n"
pause
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50552127/edit) your question to contain proper code listings (click on the `{}` abve the input window or indent all lines by four spaces. ATM due to wrong line breaks your code is hardly readable.

Comment: I think your code is fine and you're passing it some garbage data, I get the same Generic failure exception when I run `Test-Connection "1" -Count 1 -Quiet`.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Correct. Seems to be the data issue and nothing to do with the script.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: I just tried the Test-Connection "1" as you said, but when I put my computer name instead of 1 it returns the value $true. When I am testing this gui I am using my computer name to test with so I'm still unsure about the error.

Comment: @LotPings: I did indent my code, but I went through all the code and reindented it and fixed that line break error.

Comment: I just wrote a quick script to demonstrate what I am trying to do, I added it to the end of my post.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue, there was an error with how my script was passing the variables. 
The manual input method of entering the computer names in the parent form was not correctly passing the variable out of it's script box.

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `Where` method with a delegate like that.  It works, but it's really not how PowerShell is typically written.  PowerShell's LINQ support is awkward at best, so that style pattern isn't really in line with normal style.  I would expect something like this:

```
$OnlineHosts = foreach ($HostName in $HostList) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $HostName -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $HostName
    }
}

$OfflineHosts = $HostList | Where-Object { $_ -notin $OnlineHosts }
```

Or like this:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$OnlineHosts = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$OfflineHosts = @()

foreach ($HostName in $HostList) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $HostName -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $OnlineHosts.Add($HostName)
    }
    else {
        $OfflineHosts.Add($HostName)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to point out that the `Where` and `ForEach` methods in PowerShell have nothing to do with LINQ. They are special built-ins in the PowerShell runtime and take scriptblocks not delegates (a subtle distinction I realize.) Your first solution is optimal for this case where you only want the positive set. The second solution has a small problem in that `ArrayList.Add` returns a value so you'll get a bunch of numbers written to the output stream that you probably don't want. Casting the result of the `Add`s to `[void]` will fix that problem. (I generally avoid ArrayList for this reason)

Comment: @BrucePayette My point isn't that the Where method is LINQ, it's that it's LINQ-like. If you're coming from C# 4.0, you can't easily use that pattern in PowerShell. Collection.Where() is less readable and maintainable simply because it's rare. That makes it a bad pattern. It isn't even easily discoverable with `Get-Member`, nor is it readily available in the C# doc. The only documentation I find is a blurb in `Where-Object` and some bullets in `about_Windows_PowerShell_4.0` that the syntax changed. It is for most intents and purposes an undocumented language construct.